# Object Oriented Programing

Tags: php

I am doing a project on developing an Institute Information System. There are three types of users, Administrator, Faculty members and the student users. All these classes have some particular properties in common. How do I implement this object oriented model in PHP so that the usability of code should increase. It would be really helpful if someone could suggest books or links.
Thanks

Comment: that's a very broad question you have (with no question mark).

Comment: tell me what do you think of the problem? how do you prefer ?

Comment: I want to know is it possible to create an object oriented model in php  where I can directly inherit the common properties from a class? And being just a beginner in PHP it would be good if you could suggest me where to begin from?

Comment: To read about object inheritance in PHP, why not start with the manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest you to look at some of the available frameworks such as `Yii`, `CodeIgniter`, `Zend` and maybe others that provide some structure for a project like this.

Most of the MVC frameworks support also Object Oriented Programming in PHP.

For me, in my opinion `YII` has the most OOP approach as it is completely based on and does not support backward compatibility with PHP 5.1 or prior.

For more information I suggest you to look at [this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/features/) with an overview of the features.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is a (very) broad question. It sounds like you want to have an abstract class User with the shared functions/properties

```
<?php
abstract class User {
    public function __construct() { /* what to do on initiation */ }

    /* -- Common functions here --  */
}

class Admin extends User {
   /* -- Admin only functions -- */
}

class Faculty extends User {
   /* -- Faculty only functions -- */
}

class Student extends User {
   /* -- Student only functions -- */
}
```

I'd recommend looking through the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php) on the proper use of classes/objects.